# pandas dataframe, uniquifying a column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with two columns. Example:

```
index       result
LI00066994  0.740688
LI00066994  0.742431
LI00066994  0.741826
LI00066994  0.741328
LI00066994  0.741826
LI00066994  0.741328
LI00073078  0.741121
LI00073078  0.752619
LI00073078  0.757116
LI00073078  0.752619
LI00073078  0.757116
LI00073078  0.752619
```

Now I want to have a dataframe, where my index is unique, while keeping all corresponding results - they should be in different columns (result 1, result2, result3 ...).

Desired output:

```
index       result1   result2  result3  result4  result5  result6
LI00066994  0.740688 0.742431 0.741826 0.741328 0.741826 0.741328
LI00073078  0.741121 0.752619 0.757116 0.752619 0.757116 0.752619
```

Anyone an idea how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
d = """index       result
LI00066994  0.740688
LI00066994  0.742431
LI00066994  0.741826
LI00066994  0.741328
LI00066994  0.741826
LI00066994  0.741328
LI00073078  0.741121
LI00073078  0.752619
LI00073078  0.757116
LI00073078  0.752619
LI00073078  0.757116
LI00073078  0.752619
LI00073078  0.752620"""

df = pd.read_csv(pd.core.common.StringIO(d), sep='\s+')

df_out = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame({name: df_['result'].values}).T for name, df_ in df.groupby('index')])
df_out = df_out.rename(columns=lambda x: 'result' + str(x))
df_out = df_out.reset_index()
print df_out
```

Yielding:

```
        index  result0  result1  result2  result3  result4  result5  result6  
0  LI00066994    0.741    0.742    0.742    0.741    0.742    0.741      NaN  
1  LI00073078    0.741    0.753    0.757    0.753    0.757    0.753    0.753
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how to do this with just pandas. But if you are happy to throw numpy into the mix give this a shot:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

index = [
    'LI00066994',  'LI00066994',  'LI00066994',  
    'LI00066994',  'LI00066994',  'LI00066994',  
    'LI00073078',  'LI00073078',  'LI00073078',  
    'LI00073078',  'LI00073078',  'LI00073078']
data = [
    0.740688, 0.742431, 0.741826, 0.741328, 
    0.741826, 0.741328, 0.741121, 0.752619, 
    0.757116, 0.752619, 0.757116, 0.752619]
columns=['result']
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, index=index, columns=columns)

unique_index = np.unique(df.index)
new_data = np.vstack([df.T[lookup] for lookup in unique_index])

new_df = pd.DataFrame(data=new_data, index=unique_index)
```